# Bootstrap 5 menu shaking on hover

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

Hello i have problem with shaking, when i hover on link.nav where i've added border-bottom to show on hover.

```
<section id="main_header">
<div class="container-fluid mainbar-bg py-1">
    <div class="container">
       
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar w/ text</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
      <!--<span class="navbar-text">
        Navbar text with an inline element
      </span>-->
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item mx-4 py-4">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Strona Główna<br>
              <span class="nav-link-down">Ekran początkowy</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item mx-4 py-4">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Profil<br>
              <span class="nav-link-down">Zarządzanie</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item mx-4 py-4">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</nav>


    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

CSS style:

```
.nav-link-down {
    font-size: 0.75rem;
    color: #b1b1b1;
}

.nav-link.active {
    color: #1f1e2e!important;
}

.nav-link {
    color: #1f1e2e!important;
}

.nav-link:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px red solid;
}
```

(I've changed background to dark to show you a container shaking too)
https://www.codeply.com/p/XrkrwVnrJD

[Problem gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2R9gM.gif)

Comment: Because you are giving `border-bottom: 1px` on hovering `<a>` element, so that 1px of height is increased on hovering, that's the shake effect.

Comment: @ShashankGb How can i fix it?

Comment: Easy hack is to add `border-bottom: 1px #212529 solid;`  to `.nav-link` then `border-bottom: 1px red solid;` keep it as it is in `.nav-link:hover`, now `1px` is added previously before hovering so there should be no shaking effect

Comment: @ShashankGb It works, thank you my brother.

Comment: Posted as answer, If it solved your question, [mark as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy hack is to add `border-bottom: 1px #212529 solid;` to `.nav-link`, now 1px of `border-bottom` is added previously before hovering and it is hided because of same background-color so there should be no shaking effect.

Here is a demo. (Run it in the full page)

```css
.nav-link-down {
    font-size: 0.75rem;
    color: #b1b1b1;
}

.nav-link.active {
    color: #ffffff!important;
}

.nav-link {
    color: #ffffff!important;
    border-bottom: 1px #212529 solid;
}

.nav-link:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px red solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section id="main_header">
<div class="container-fluid bg-dark py-1">
    <div class="container">
       
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar w/ text</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
      <!--<span class="navbar-text">
        Navbar text with an inline element
      </span>-->
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item mx-4 py-4">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Strona Główna<br>
              <span class="nav-link-down">Ekran początkowy</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item mx-4 py-4">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Profil<br>
              <span class="nav-link-down">Zarządzanie</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item mx-4 py-4">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</nav>


    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you add the nav-link to a border and make its color transparent.

```
enter code here
.nav-link {
color: #1f1e2e!important;
border-bottom: 1px solid transprant;
```

}

then

```
enter code here.nav-link:hover {
border-bottom: 1px solid red;
```

}